# Finding specific text and appending text after or deleting text before

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any way find a line in an html file and append text to it using filestreams? I only know how to either replace it entirely or only append at the end of the file. Here's what I have so far:

```
index = fs.readFile(filename, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
    if (err) return console.log(err);
    fs.find("base href=");
    fs.writeFile(filename, data.replace(current, changeTo), 'utf8', function 
    (err) {//So here, instead of replacing, can I instead find 'current' and append 'changeTo' instead?
        if (err) return console.log(err);
    })
})
```

So say that my file is called index.html and in the middle of index.html (not at the end or beginning) there is a line that says "Helo". I want to find "Hel" and appened an "l" to it. current and changeTo are just strings.

Comment: use string `indexOf` method to find that

Comment: I see, but how would I then append to the file at that position? Or are you saying to not use filestream read/write?

Comment: load the contents of a text file into a javascript variable and with indexOf and substr methods find and replace newValue to oldValue. [replace at specific index demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8PdbG/)